# Relationship semisimple matrices and semisimple modules.

Tags: matrices, ring-theory, diagonalization, semi-simple-rings

For a commutative ring (if necessary field) $R$, we say a square matrix $X$ over $R $is semisimple iff $X$ is diagonalizable.

On the other hand, R-Module $M$ is semisimple iff $M$ is direct sum of irreducible modules (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_module).

Is there relation  each definition?

Moreover I often see the word "semisimple" e.g. "semisimple ring", "semisimple Lie alg." Is it used "semisimple" by same meaning?

Comment: I switched "diagolanliazion" with "diagonalizable" because I felt that's what you meant, but you can let us know if that's not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_operator), you call a linear operator $T$ semisimple if every $T$ invariant subspace has a direct summand complement.

If $T$ operates on $V$, I believe this is referring to the module structure on $V$ given by the polynomial ring $k[T]$ on $V$.  It means that $V$ becomes a semisimple $k[T]$ module in the sense of module theory.

Note that the wiki article additionally says that it becomes equivalent to $T$ being diagonalizable if $k$ is an algebraically closed field.  You can still talk about $V_R$ being a semisimple $R[T]$ module in terms of invariant subspaces having complements, but I don't think you have the link to diagonalizability anymore.

Also note that being a semisimple *ring* is more stringent: all of $R$'s modules have to be semisimple for $R$ to be a semisimple ring. On the other hand, every ring has *some* semisimple modules.